# PreSelection of Checkbox from DataSource while Loading application first time in java/Android

Tags: java, android

I am developing android application using Paging library in MVVM pattern. I have used `PositionalDataSource` to create an item.

I want a certain number of items to be preselected when I load my application first time.

I tried many way but it didn't work:

```
private List<Integer> listOfPreSelectedPosition = new ArrayList<>((Arrays.asList(4,7,10,90)));//These positions to be preselected
private List<Item> createNewItemsMatchingRequestedSize(int startPosition, int pagecount) {
    List<Item> newItems = new ArrayList<>();
    // actual load code here
    for (int i = 0; i < pagecount; i++) {
        Item item = new Item("Item " + i + " " + "startPosition(" + startPosition + ")");

        //listOfPreSelectedPosition.contains(startPosition + i) is boolean to check wheck it's true or not
        if (listOfPreSelectedPosition.contains(startPosition + i)) {
            item.setSelected(true);
            item.setListofPreSelectedPosition(listOfPreSelectedPosition);
            Log.e(TAG, "preSelected item is : " + item  );
            Log.e(TAG, "listOfPreSelectedPosition : " + listOfPreSelectedPosition  );
        }
        newItems.add(item);
    }
    return newItems;
}
```

How can i pass the `item.setSelected` to `customAdapter` so that I can make `holder.checkbox.SetChecked(true)` of these preselected items?

My updated gitlink for your more reference: https://github.com/kumarjitendra

Comment: Please take a minute and format the rest of your post so it is easier for folks to read.

Comment: I highly recommend reading [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and more specifically the "Spelling, grammar and formatting" section. I've corrected this post, and fixed some of the common mistakes, but on future posts reading this article would go a long way to making high quality posts for future visitors.